# VS 2013, отключение автоматического разворачивания методов

Tags: visual-studio-2013

При копипасте иногда разворачиваются все методы, которые ниже места вставки кода. Как отключить эту настройку? Т.е. чтобы при любой вставке кода в произвольное место - методы оставались свернутыми.

Comment: Самый простой способ исправить что-то в Visual Studio - запостить баг на [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/) с указанием точных шагов. Без заплюсованного багрепорта они такую мелочёвку обчыно не чинят.

Comment: Увы, у меня с английским туго. Если найдется добрый человек, который запостит и выложит сюда ссылку - буду признателен, и на я один.

Comment: А если сразу после вставки жать кнопку или хоткей "fold all"?

Comment: Я использую комбинацию Ctrl+M Ctrl+O, но муторно это когда постоянно по классам переходы идут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вся информация о сокрытии фрагментов кода, закладках и т.д. (так называемый outlining) хранится в файле *.suo, все пути в котором абсолютны. Естественно, при переносе проекта все абсолютные пути перестают быть актуальными и элементы outlining пропадают.

Из файла *.suo можно понять, что он напрямую хранит структуры всех файлов с прямым указанием номеров строк к которым применяется тот или иной элемент outlining. Очевидно, при определенных условиях, при вставке фрагмента кода, номера строк в *.suo не пересчитываются, что и приводит к "падению" всего форматирования. Что это за "определенные условия", задуманы ли они 
разработчиками или являются банальным багом - вопрос отдельного исследования.

*P.S. Я прямо сейчас пробовал вставлять различные фрагменты кода разного размера и пришел к выводу, что outlining не пересчитывается, если вставляемый фрагмент содержит одну или более незакрытую скобку. Во всех остальных случаях VS2013(Английская) отработала верно и сохранила состояние outlining после вставленного фрагмента.*

*P.S.S. Если проблема наблюдается и вы уверены, что со скобками все ОК, попробуйте перед вставкой крупного фрагмента кода делать файл .suo  "только для чтения".*

Comment: Чем же должно помочь делание suo-файла readonly? Там же после этого неактуальные номера строк останутся?

Comment: Мы может только гадать когда и как именно пересчитываются номера строк. Возможно студия (по аналогии с intellisense) просто не успевает проанализировать большой фрагмент вставленного кода и на мгновение считает, что синтаксис неверен,  удаляя всю разметку после него.  В общем попробовать в данном случае быстрее чем рассуждать)

Answer (score 4):

*Перенес ответ из комментария*

---

Никак. Это глюк. Глюки не настраиваются. Возможно, в VS 2015 починят. Это если вы пишете на дотнете, для двух языков которого вышел новый компилятор. В противном случае вряд ли. Но всё равно надейтесь на лучшее. А вдруг?

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, всё последующее разворачивается только если то, что вставлено не даёт корректную структуру. Например, если не скопирована закрывающая метод фигурная скобка.

Хотя допускаю, что в вопросе речь идёт о какой-то другой ситуации.

Comment: Верно, но не только это. Например если переносите проект в другую папку и открываете его - все методы опять открыты. И опять приходится все сворачивать. Причем даже нету комбинации аналога: Ctrl+M Ctrl+O (да и она не идеальна, например не сворачивает битовые перечисления и т.д.), которая бы позволила сразу свернуть все классы в проекте. Это очень раздражает, особенно когда проект большой и мечешься по разным классам.

Comment: Начну конкурс. Может у девелоперов уже созрело решение этого вопроса, или какие либо домашние заготовки. Переход на VS 2015 в моем случае не подойдет из-за несовместимости некоторых компонентов.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу немножко в сторону.
Несколько странной выглядит эта зависимость от сворачивания методов.

Могу допустить, что вашу проблему следует решить, изменив способ ориентирования в больших проектах.

Например, для меня очень удачным оказался ReSharper с его функцией "Go to everything..." (Ctrl+N). Это во многих кейсах (но не во всех) избавляет от необходимости шарить по проекту и терпеть неудобства от развёрнутых методов.

Comment: Я использую CodeLens, но всеравно неприятно когда все методы раскрыты, это так же затрудняет навигацию и визуальное восприятие класса.